# iopl()/ioperm() for MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, low-level-io

Are there equivalent functions for what iopl() does on Linux?
I don't need to use just iopl, but other related functions like outb() and inb(). Alternative question, is there an equivalent library for MacOS like sys/io.h on Linux?

Comment: The second part of your question is off-topic - software recommendations are not on-topic here on SO.

Comment: Since iopl and ioperm are defined in sys/io.h, the question could have been for an alternative library as well